# Can i reassign the values to same variables in python

Tags: python, string

I have this variable in python

```
DATE_FILENAME =  datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%b-%d-%Y-%I%M%p")
```

Now this is supposed to have diff value every time .
But i have heard that strings are immutable does it mean that it will hold only one value

This is the result  `_May-22-2011-1002PM.tar.gz`

my script took 3 minutes for backing up 8 folders but all have the same date_filename part. so i wanted to know why it didn't chnaged

Comment: No idea what the sense of this question should be? More context please and explain _clearly_ what is not working here for you...

Comment: i mean every minute , i making backups and i am using that as the name of file . don't it is suppose to have diff name everyminute. or i am wrong

Comment: It will have a different name for each time that line is executed, but it will not change its value each time it's used, if that's what you want.

Comment: @Mahakaal: please read the Python tutorial...I don't think that SO should be used for every beginner question that pops up that are covered by reading the tutorial and with a reasonable amount of programming background -1

Comment: @sentinel , i agree that previous questions regarding operator was basic , but this one is tricky . i read the tutorial and thats why i am writing basic scripts . but u can't say not to ask ques here. Almost 70% questions solutions can be found in any book but still people ask . thats why the forum is for. If u think its too basic then don't answer. So many answers have been given and i have learnt much more by @katrielalex answer than what i asked for

Comment: Sorry, but looking at the history of your question: most of them are of them quality: throwing a sentence or two without reasonable context at us. I suggest reading http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html - providing reasonable context with a question is the best success for getting help instead of downvotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Let me clarify: you define this constant once in your module? In that case it will not change; you have to update the name binding every time you want to write a file. An easy way to do this is to write a little function `get_name` which will generate the new name every time you call it.

The reason the string doesn't change is that if this code is at module level (no indents) then it will only be executed once, at the time that the module is executed. It won't change after that.

This is a separate issue from the immutability of strings.

---

When this line is executed, the interpreter will look up the system time, format it according to the string argument of `strftime`, and store the value in the variable.

There is an important point to make here, about name binding in Python. Consider the line

```
foo = 1
```

You may wonder what happens behind-the-scenes here. When the interpreter sees this line, it does two things:

1. It creates an integer object and stores it in an internal table somewhere.
2. It "binds" the name `foo` to this object; in other words, it records the fact that `foo` means this object in an internal table somewhere.

The important point is that `foo` is just a name for the object we might call 1. In particular, you can make `foo` a name for something else by rebinding it, say `foo = 2`. But **you can't change `1`**!

In exactly the same way, you can't change the datetime string you might create. That object is immutable. But you can make names point to different strings or indeed any type of different object!

Comment: thanks buddy , i really appreciate ur time to share this knowledge with me . I got my mistake. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable, but name bindings aren't.  You can assign a new value to `DATE_FILENAME` at any time you want to.

If you want `DATE_FILENAME` to have a different value each time it is *accessed*, that is a bit harder.  I guess you could do that by defining a class and overriding the `__str__()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `DATE_FILENAME` will only hold a constant value once it is assigned, but it has nothing to do with strings being immutable, that's just how variable assignment works in Python. Variables are just names, assignment to a variable means you are asking the computer to compute the expression on the right hand side, and store its value into the name on the left hand side.

If you want the `DATE_FILENAME` to be different every time you use it, you are looking for something called a **lazily evaluated value**, something that recomputes the value based on its assignment expression every time you use it (by referring to it). The natural way to do it in Python is to put `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%b-%d-%Y-%I%M%p")` into a function.

```
def datetime_now_in_string():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%b-%d-%Y-%I%M%p")

DATE_FILENAME = datetime_now_in_string()
```

or

```
date_filename = lambda: datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%b-%d-%Y-%I%M%p")

file_name = date_filename() + '.txt'
```

You get the idea.

Comment: thanks man , i get the idea now

Answer (score 0):

The immutability of an object means, that once the object has been created in a memory, it can only be destroyed. In context of string:

```
DATE_FILENAME =  datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%b-%d-%Y-%I%M%p") 
id(DATE_FILENAME) 
>>> 139734827954224
DATE_FILENAME = DATE_FILENAME.upper() # creating a new string here
id(DATE_FILENAME) 
>>> 30526192
```